# Subversion commit failed on Mac OS X with error "no such table: rep_cache"

Tags: svn, macos

I created a subversion repository, imported an empty structure, checked out the repo, added a file to the working copy and tried commiting the working copy with the following commands:

```
svnadmin create mysvn

svn import -m "initial empty structure" test/ file:///tmp/mysvn

svn co file:///tmp/mysvn mywc

svn ci -m "test"
```

The commit failed with the following error:

Transmitting file data .svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: While preparing '/tmp/mywc' for commit
svn: no such table: rep_cache

I am running Mac OS X 10.6.3 and subversion 1.6.5.

Did I miss any steps or Mac specific commands?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After googling a bit I found this link: http://www.cumps.be/howto-installing-subversion-on-readynas-nv/#div-comment-1177
I'm not sure it's the same issue, but maybe it's worth a try.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Changing the enable-rep-cache = false fixed the issue. 

I did go that same page several times before but never caught the comment.

Answer (score 1):

Adding this to SVNREPOS/db/fsfs.conf

`enable-rep-sharing = false`

Worked for me. Using subversion 1.6.13 Mac OS 10.6 Snow Leopard.

Comment: This worked for me, after I upgraded from version 1.6.12 to 1.6.13.

Answer (score 0):

For those that don't want to dig... edit fsfs.conf in your svn repository (the repository not the local copy) directory, uncomment the line (or add if it's not there):

```
enable-rep-cache = false
```

Worked like a charm for me!

Answer (score 0):

"enable-repcache = false" worked for me as well. I just registered to stackoverflow and for some reason can't 'up' the correct solution (I apparently don't have enough reputation yet).